# Tomcat connection pooling with prepared statement cache

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

Having upgraded from DBCP connection pooling to Tomcat's own implementation (based on the excellent comparison [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Introduction)); I'm a little confused as to why they've dropped these 2 properties, while keeping everything else:

```
poolPreparedStatements="true"
maxOpenPreparedStatements="10000"
```

Does this mean that prepared statement pooling is not supported in this implementation? And does each connection maintain its own pool of prepared statements by default?

I've spent a considerable time researching this and have found no clear answer!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tomcat's (fairly) new jdbc-pool does have a statement cache, too.
You can enable and configure it using a `JDBC interceptor`, which is set as a **JDBC property** during **pool creation**.
Please have a [look at the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache) for more information and which configuration possibilities exist.

It's basically done this way:

```
      PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
      p.setUrl("jdbc:your-jdbc-url");
      p.setDriverClassName("your.jdbc.driver.class");
      p.setUsername("user");
      p.setPassword("password");
      p.setJdbcInterceptors(
        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache");
      DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
      datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
```